# Real-Time Calculation in Javascript: Based on text field and fixed price rate of an item

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a form which has one field to enter the quantity of an item.

I want to calculate the cost of the item based on fixed price and the quantity.

I am wondering how can I achieve it through javascript.

[image: This is what I want]

I want to host each item price in an array - for the sake of later adding more product.

Please help me, refer to the picture below to understand what I am asking. I am really sorry for my bad english.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: @Teemu - I think https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript first

Answer (score 0):

```
element.onkeypress = function() { // element should be your input field
    var value = this.value; // get the value of the field
    value *= cost; // multiply value by cost and save result; change cost to suit your needs
    // set outputelement to the element where you show the result
    outputelement.innerHTML = value; // set the text of the output field to the result;
}
```